# URL loading the wrong view - Django

Tags: python, django, url, view

Really struggling with this one.  For some reason I can't get my URL to load the correct view.  The site loads the home page correctly but then when I add on the extesion to acess another one of my apps, it just reloads the home page.  It doesnt throw any errors or anything, it just wond direct to the correct page.

This is my base URL file:

```
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', blog_views.home),
    path('<username>/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('community/', include('community.urls')),
```

Start of the `Blog` URL file:

```
path('', LogListView.as_view(), name='log'),
```

This is the `Blog` views file:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    user_name = request.user.username
    return HttpResponseRedirect(f'{user_name}/')

class LogListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/log-main.html'
    login_url = 'login/'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_added']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LogListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)
        return context
```

*The `home` function above sutomatically directs each user to thier specific home page by placing thier username at the start of the URL path.*

Then here is my `Community` app URL file:

```
path('', CommunityListView.as_view(), name='community'),
```

And the `Community` view file:

```
class CommunityListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community/community.html'
    context_object_name = 'postss'
    ordering = ['-date_added']

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        active_user = self.request.user
        active_user_following = active_user.following.values_list('user_id', flat=True)
        following_user_objects = []
        for id in active_user_following:
            followed = User.objects.get(id=id)
            following_user_objects.append(followed)
            print(followed)
        print(following_user_objects)
        print(active_user_following)
        return WILT.objects.filter(user__in=following_user_objects)
```

As I mentioned above, when I add `/community/` to the URL path, it jsut relaods the main home page.  I've been going through this for hours with no luck.

Comment: How you are managing login required.. is user logged in when you are trying to access home route?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing a mistake in this line.

```
path('', CommunityListView.as_view(), name='community'),
```

Try this:

```
path('communityList/', CommunityListView.as_view(), name='community'),
```

You cannot call empty url path, because it is assign to `home` page